# R Shiny Datatable Child Row Selection and Info Issue

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I am having an issue selecting the child rows in a R Shiny DT Table with JS callback.

When expanding the parent row, I try to select the child rows, and all rows are selected in that child (including child's background).
If I select 2nd child row, the background is deselcted and it shows my 2 childs selected (every other click selects all child rows, then shows ones selected repeatedly)

Also, how to get the information on which child rows are selected?

Thank you very much!
Alex B

I am trying to play with the datatable settings in the JS callback.

```
'''

library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)

ui <- fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput(width = "100%", "table"))

server <- function(input, output) {

output$table = DT::renderDataTable({

mtcars_dt = data.table(mtcars)
setkey(mtcars_dt,mpg,cyl)
mpg_dt = unique(mtcars_dt[, list(mpg, cyl)])
setkey(mpg_dt, mpg, cyl)
cyl_dt = unique(mtcars_dt[, list(cyl)])
setkey(cyl_dt, cyl)

mtcars_dt = mtcars_dt[, toJSON(.SD), by = list(mpg,cyl)]
setnames(mtcars_dt,'V1','mtcars')
mtcars_dt[, ' ' := '&#9658;']


df1 = mtcars_dt
df1 = df1[c(1,6),]

setcolorder(df1, c(length(df1),c(1:(length(df1) - 1))))



DT::datatable(
  data = df1,
  rownames = FALSE,
  escape = FALSE,
  selection="multiple",
  options = list(
    # dom = 'Bfrti',
    stripeClasses = list(),
    deferRender = TRUE,
    # scrollX = TRUE,
    pageLength = 25,
    scrollY = "1000",
    scroller = TRUE,
    scollCollapse = TRUE,
    lengthMenu = c(20, 50, 100, 500),
    searchHighlight = TRUE,
    tabIndex = 1,
    columnDefs = list(
      list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 0),
      list(visible = FALSE, targets = -1 )
    )
  ),
  callback = JS("

                //table.header().to$().css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'})

                table.column(01).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'})

                var table_id = 1000

                // Format child object into another table
                var format = function(table_id, columns) {
                if(columns != null){ 

                var result = ('<table id=\"' + table_id + '\"><thead><tr>')
                for (var i in columns){
                result += '<th>' + columns[i] + '</th>'
                }
                result += '</tr></thead></table>'

                return result

                }else{
                return ''
                }
                }

                var format_datatable = function( table_id, newtable, columns) {
                if(newtable != null){


                var column_defs = []

                for (var i in columns)
                {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                column_defs[i] = {'data': columns[i], 'targets': parseInt(i), 'orderable': false, 'className': 'details-control'}
                }

                else
                {
                column_defs[i] = {'data': columns[i], 'targets': parseInt(i)}
                }
                }

                /*    alert(JSON.stringify(column_defs)) */


                //var printTable = document.getElementById(newtable)
                //document.write(newtable)
                //document.write(columns)


                var subtable = $(('table#' + table_id)).DataTable({
                'data': newtable,
                'autoWidth': false, 
                'deferRender': true,
                'stripeClasses': [],
                'info': false, 
                'select': { style: 'os',
                },
                'lengthChange': false, 
                'ordering': false, 
                'paging': false, 
                'scrollX': false, 
                'scrollY': false, 
                'searching': false,
                'columnDefs': column_defs
                }).draw()

                }
                }

                table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {

                var td = $(this)
                var table = $(td).closest('table')
                var row = $(table).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr'))


                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                row.child.hide()
                td.html('&#9658;')
                }
                else
                {
                var row_data = row.data()

                if (!Array.isArray(row_data))
                {
                row_data = Object.keys(row_data).map(function (key) {
                return row_data[key]
                });
                }

                var newtable = JSON.parse(row_data[row_data.length-1])
                var columns = Object.keys(newtable[0])

                table_id++

                row.child(format(table_id, columns)).show()
                format_datatable(table_id, newtable, columns)
                console.log(table_id)
                td.html('&#9660;')
                }

                })


                ")
  )
})

observe({
print(input$table_rows_selected)
print(input$newtable_rows_selected)

})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

'''
```

I would like to highlight individual child rows and know which child rows are selected.  Currently it highlights all child rows each time it clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt. This works, but the selection on the main table is disabled.

```
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)

initComplete <- paste(
  "function(settings){",
  "  var table = settings.oInstance.api();",
  "  var tbl = table.table().node();",
  "  var id = $(tbl).closest('.dataTable').attr('id');",
  "  table.on('click', 'tbody tr', function(){",
  "    // send selected columns to Shiny",
  "    setTimeout(function(){",
  "      var indexes = table.rows({selected:true}).indexes();",
  "      var indices = Array(indexes.length);",
  "      for(var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i){",
  "        indices[i] = indexes[i];",
  "      }",
  "      Shiny.setInputValue('childrow_rows_selected', {child: id, rows: indices});",
  "    },0);",
  "  });",
  "}",
  sep = "\n"
)

ui <- fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput(width = "100%", "table"))

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table = DT::renderDataTable({

    mtcars_dt = data.table(mtcars)
    setkey(mtcars_dt,mpg,cyl)
    mpg_dt = unique(mtcars_dt[, list(mpg, cyl)])
    setkey(mpg_dt, mpg, cyl)
    cyl_dt = unique(mtcars_dt[, list(cyl)])
    setkey(cyl_dt, cyl)

    mtcars_dt = mtcars_dt[, toJSON(.SD), by = list(mpg,cyl)]
    setnames(mtcars_dt,'V1','mtcars')
    mtcars_dt[, ' ' := '&#9658;']


    df1 = mtcars_dt
    df1 = df1[c(1,6),]

    setcolorder(df1, c(length(df1),c(1:(length(df1) - 1))))

    DT::datatable(
      data = df1,
      rownames = FALSE,
      escape = FALSE,
      selection = "none",
      extensions = "Select",
      options = list(
        # dom = 'Bfrti',
        stripeClasses = list(),
        deferRender = TRUE,
        # scrollX = TRUE,
        pageLength = 25,
        scrollY = "1000",
        scroller = TRUE,
        scollCollapse = TRUE,
        lengthMenu = c(20, 50, 100, 500),
        searchHighlight = TRUE,
        tabIndex = 1,
        columnDefs = list(
          list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 0),
          list(visible = FALSE, targets = -1 )
        )
      ),
      callback = JS("

                    table.column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});

                    // var table_id = 1000

                    // Format child object into another table
                    var format = function(table_id, columns) {
                    if(columns != null){ 

                    var result = ('<table id=\"' + table_id + '\"><thead><tr>')
                    for (var i in columns){
                    result += '<th>' + columns[i] + '</th>'
                    }
                    result += '</tr></thead></table>'

                    return result

                    }else{
                    return ''
                    }
                    }

                    var format_datatable = function( table_id, newtable, columns) {
                    if(newtable != null){


                    var column_defs = []

                    for (var i in columns)
                    {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                    column_defs[i] = {'data': columns[i], 'targets': parseInt(i), 'orderable': false, 'className': 'details-control'}
                    }

                    else
                    {
                    column_defs[i] = {'data': columns[i], 'targets': parseInt(i)}
                    }
                    }

                    var subtable = $(('table#' + table_id)).DataTable({
                    'data': newtable,",
                    sprintf("initComplete: %s,", initComplete),
"                    'autoWidth': false, 
                    'deferRender': true,
                    'stripeClasses': [],
                    'info': false, 
                    'select': {style: 'multi'},
                    'lengthChange': false, 
                    'ordering': false, 
                    'paging': false, 
                    'scrollX': false, 
                    'scrollY': false, 
                    'searching': false,
                    'columnDefs': column_defs
                    }).draw()

                    }
                    }

                    table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {

                    var td = $(this);
                    var table = $(td).closest('table');
                    var row = $(table).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr'));
                    var table_id = 'child' + row.index();

                    if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    row.child.hide();
                    td.html('&#9658;');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    var row_data = row.data();

                    if (!Array.isArray(row_data))
                    {
                    row_data = Object.keys(row_data).map(function (key) {
                    return row_data[key];
                    });
                    }

                    var newtable = JSON.parse(row_data[row_data.length-1])
                    var columns = Object.keys(newtable[0])

                    //table_id++

                    row.child(format(table_id, columns)).show()
                    format_datatable(table_id, newtable, columns)
                    console.log(table_id)
                    td.html('&#9660;')
                    }

                    })

                    ")
      )
  })

  observe({
#    print(input$table_rows_selected)
#    print(input$newtable_rows_selected)
    print(input$childrow_rows_selected)

  })

  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: See a better example [here](https://gist.github.com/stla/e3607e3cf87ddbe70b7134d4a1c874d9#file-dt_childtables_shiny-r).